# AWS Cognito SAML - DEV, Stage server is Ok, But production server is not acting. ( Internal Server Error )

Tags: amazon-cognito, saml, saml-2.0, aws-sso

Hello Everybody,

Currently, I've got some strange issue.
I have developed the SAML SSO for AWS Cognito, and it works very well on DEV, STAGE server.

But production server is not acting well.
I made a SAMLResponse paramter and send it back to Cognito to ACS URL.

I mean that I attemped to access the '...amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse' ACS URL.

But I get back the following result.

- Request URL
  https://XXXXX.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse
- Response URL (Error message)
  https://XXXXX.com/login/#error_description=Error+in+SAML+response+processing%3A+Internal+server+error.+&error=server_error

As a result, I get the **'Internal Server Error'** message.

Would you know why it happen?

When I check, a SAMLResponse paramter has no problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I figure out the issue in mine. It was because my Cognito account was broken. So it works when using a different account. What broke my account is when I tried using boto3 Cognito Client function called `admin_link_provider_for_user`.